# Break Timestamp to Date and Time

Tags: java, timestamp

How to break java,sql.Timestamp of format **yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fffffffff** to Date and Time where date is of form dd-mm-yyyy and time is of form hh:mm:ss.

I tried to do it.But no success till yet.Please help me .

Comment: please upload the code that you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
//If you Want Date
java.sql.Timestamp  sqlDate=resultSet.getTimestamp("dateColumn");<--From Database
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");//One
System.out.println(sdf.format(sqlDate));
//If you Want time 
SimpleDateFormat sdf1=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:SS.sss");//Two
System.out.println(sdf1.format(sqlDate));
```